# Flash and _root and levels - Loading SWF into another SWF

Tags: flash, root, levels

I'm loading an old formula calculator into a new project I'm working on; pretty simple...

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("calc_mc", 0);
loadMovie("calc.swf", calc_mc);
```

Everything's fine...But, these commands clear the 'hints' in the form fields in the original calc.swf

```
if (my_txt != null) {
    var mc = my_txt._name + "Hint";
    if (my_txt.length > 0) {
        _root[mc]._visible = false;
    } else {
        _root[mc]._visible = true;
    }
}
_root[this._name + "Hint"]._visible = false;
```

SWF works fine on it's own, but once it's loaded into the new project, the hints dont clear. I know _root is garbling it somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once loaded in a new movie, `_root` references the **Main Movie** root timeline, so your _root commands fails on the loaded movie.

You should change them in a `_parent`..... notation.
For example if your _root command is 2 level nested in the loaded movie, you can refer to root
as `_parent._parent`

or you can use this ugly solution:

```
_root.calc_mc..............
```

with this one the standalone swf will not work anymore.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - so if I use _root in SWF B, and load it into SWF A level 1 ("calc_mc", 1); , I should change the root notation to _parent correct? - _parent[this._name + "Hint"]._visible = false;

Comment: No, it depends on where the _root.... instruction is located: if it is on a frame of the main timeline of SWF B, then you can use a single _parent. If it is on the timeline of a movie of SWF B, then you must use _parent._parent, and so on.

Comment: Man, this is driving me nuts - the _root instruction lives on an actions layer in the main timeline of the swf...loading it into level 1 of the other swf, and changing to _parent doesn't seem to be affecting it at all. Does loading it in level0 actually do the trick?

Comment: if it lives on the main timeline of the swf, then you can simply remove the _root prefix: use this[this._name + "Hint"]........., because on the root timeline _root and this are equivalent, but this works even if loaded in another movie.

Comment: the ugly one works; much prettier than my list of onSetFocus, onKillFocus events. still no luck on just 'this' though...so hard to troubleshoot with no errors thrown.